# Mockito when-thenReturn with SharedPreference value

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I'm doing my first deep dive into unit testing with Mockito, so please bear with me. I'm working on this test:

```
class PasswordStateManagerTest {

    private lateinit var passwordStateManager: PasswordStateManager

    @MockK
    private lateinit var mockContext: Context

    @MockK
    private lateinit var mockSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, true)
        every{ mockContext.getApplicationSharedPreferences() } returns mockSharedPreferences

        // this is the line that won't compile
Mockito.when(mockSharedPreferences.getBoolean("save_password", false)
    )
                    .thenReturn(true)

        passwordStateManager = PasswordStateManager(mockSharedPreferences)
    }    
}
```

The when.thenReturn line won't compile. It is expecting an open bracket `{` character where I am trying to execute on `.thenReturn`. As I read the docs, there is no place for an open bracket in this statement, so I must be off the rails.

Here is the part of the init method of the class being tested, which is what creates the need for the when-thenReturn line in the test:

```
init {
    willSavePassword = prefs.getBoolean("save_password", false)
}
```

Thanks for any help (and patience while I get up to speed!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `when` is a reserved keyword in Kotlin, so the compiler is interpreting this as the beginning of a `when` statement. For example:

```
when (value) {
    "value1" -> // do thing
}
```

To fix this, you can either escape the method name with backticks:

```
Mockito.`when`(mockSharedPreferences.getBoolean("save_password", false)).thenReturn(true);
```

Or, since you're using MockK anyway, just switch to another `every`:

```
every { mockSharedPreferences.getBoolean("save_password", false) } returns true
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!